# SSMS - What is the shortcut of search on edit 200 rows mode?

Tags: sql, ssms, shortcut

I want to search specific records but i don't remember related shortcut of this operation?

Do you have any recommendations? Please help me...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzPid.png)

Comment: I found some friends, this is CTRL + R, CTRL 3

Comment: Glad you got it.